# Function in Typescript check the response type passed as a generic

Tags: typescript, types

I wrote this function

```
const getData = async <T = object>(eventType: string, event: APIGatewayEvent): Promise<T> => {
  const { default: responses } = await import(path.resolve(DATA_PATH);
  const response: T = responses[eventType];
  return response;
};
```

I wrote a test to check that the function will prevent to return an object that doesn't fulfill the Type

```
it('should return a typed response', async () => {
  interface TypedResponse {
    ok: string;
  }
  const mockEvent = {};
  const response = await getDemoData<TypedResponse>('eventType', mockEvent);
  expect(response).toEqual({ message: 'this is a test response' });
});
```

I am not sure why it is not preventing to return any type of response when I set the `TypedResponse` interface

Comment: TS ***does not exist at runtime***. [The type system and type checks ***only*** exist at compile time](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). There is [no way for TS to do a runtime check](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-this-incorrect-cast-throw-a-runtime-error), and at compiletime it does not know the shape returned by `import` would be, as dynamic imports can only be `any`.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't really validate the return type, you could make a function that returns a number and make it return a string:

```
const getNumber = (): number => 
  "hello" as any as number;

const num: number = getNumber();
console.log(typeof num); // outputs "string"
```

If you want to validate that the return type is valid you will have to do it another way.